# how can i set place mark with text in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, c++

I want to mark a point in map  and place text near it. I used QgsVertexMarker to mark point .As far as now i am using tool-tip to show text. but i need clean code to show my text on map.

Following code is used to set marker at point A.

```
QgsVertexMarker * marker = new QgsVertexMarker(mPlugin->iface()->mapCanvas());
marker->setColor(Qt::black);
marker->setIconType(2);
marker->setCenter(A);
```

I need to display a text near that point . how to do by c++ code?

Comment: What did you try at your end? Did you use Google for this?

Comment: Hello Bavani, from your edit, I have now realized that you want to do it by coding. You should edit your question to make clear that you are doing it using Python or C++, and the piece of code that you are using.

Comment: i want to do by c++ coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to add one single placemark at a known place, you can use text Annotations.

[image]

Best regards,

Alexandre Neto

Comment: Please see my edit. I want to add point with text dynamically so i cant use text annotation.

Comment: again see my answer only use dynamic text through easy lable creator

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest placing a point at the said co-ordinates by creating a new point layer. then placing a point on the screen (anywhere).  Then using "Numerical Vertex Edit" (whilst in edit mode), highligh the point, and enter your coords.

The create label.  You will have to have given your layer some attribute in order to create the lable.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? Use any of the lable feautres.